# How override a template?

Tags: twig, prestashop

Following the [documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/templating/admin-views/) to override catalog.html.twig, I see that the "Hello World!" display does not work.
I cleared the cache.
I also tried to override view.html.twig with the following logic:

- file path :
  */modules/foo/views/PrestaShop/Admin/Sell/Order/Cart/view.html.twig*
- the content :

```
{% extends 'PrestaShopBundle:Admin/Sell/Order/Cart:view.html.twig' %}

{% block cart_summary %}
Hello world!
{% endblock %}
```

But unfortunately nothing works.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

overriding the admin templates require installed module.

Simply create and install your module via 'module manager' in admin panel, then inside of the module create this path "views/PrestaShop/Admin/Sell/Order/Cart/view.html.twig".

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a module, I think that I have to put the file inside the override folder, but no.

You have to create a module whit that tools of [prestashop](https://validator.prestashop.com/generator#) and the create the path in views like the other answer say.

The module can be generic and doesn't matter the hook.